# Strange bash_history when vagrant up

Tags: bash, vagrant

For some time I have a problem with my Vagrant.
At each "vagrant up", the history of my vagrant session is "corrupted" as follows:

```
exit
export TERM="vt100"
printf '41e57d38-b4f7-4e46-9c38-13873d338b86-vagrant-ssh'
exit
export TERM="vt100"
stty raw -echo
export PS1=""
export PS2=""
export PROMPT_COMMAND=""
printf bccbb768c119429488cfd109aacea6b5-pty
grep 'ostree=' /proc/cmdline
exitcode=$?
printf bccbb768c119429488cfd109aacea6b5-pty
exit $exitcode
export TERM="vt100"
stty raw -echo
export PS1=""
export PS2=""
export PROMPT_COMMAND=""
printf bccbb768c119429488cfd109aacea6b5-pty
if test -r /etc/os-release; then source /etc/os-release && test xLinux Mint = x$ID && exit; fi
if test -x /usr/bin/lsb_release; then /usr/bin/lsb_release -i 2>/dev/null | grep -qi Linux Mint && exit; fi
if test -r /etc/issue; then cat /etc/issue | grep -qi Linux Mint && exit; fi
exit 1
export TERM="vt100"
stty raw -echo
export PS1=""
export PS2=""
export PROMPT_COMMAND=""
printf bccbb768c119429488cfd109aacea6b5-pty
[ -x /usr/bin/lsb_release ] && /usr/bin/lsb_release -i 2>/dev/null | grep Trisquel
exitcode=$?
printf bccbb768c119429488cfd109aacea6b5-pty
exit $exitcode
export TERM="vt100"
stty raw -echo
export PS1=""
export PS2=""
export PROMPT_COMMAND=""
printf bccbb768c119429488cfd109aacea6b5-pty
grep 'Amazon Linux AMI' /etc/os-release
exitcode=$?
printf bccbb768c119429488cfd109aacea6b5-pty
exit $exitcode
export TERM="vt100"
```

There are about 560 lines like these.
When I delete `~/.bash_history` or use `history -c`, everything goes back to the next restart of the VM. Does this talk to anyone? How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

```
exit
export TERM="vt100"
printf '41e57d38-b4f7-4e46-9c38-13873d338b86-vagrant-ssh'
exit
export TERM="vt100"
stty raw -echo
export PS1=""
export PS2=""
export PROMPT_COMMAND=""
printf bccbb768c119429488cfd109aacea6b5-pty
exitcode=$?
printf bccbb768c119429488cfd109aacea6b5-pty
exit $exitcode
export TERM="vt100"
stty raw -echo
export PS1=""
export PS2=""
export PROMPT_COMMAND=""
printf bccbb768c119429488cfd109aacea6b5-pty
```

Those lines look like commands that are used by Vagrant to open a new communication socket (or whatever is used to communicate with the container)

About `export TERM="vt100"`, `export PS1=""`, `export PS2=""` and `export PROMPT_COMMAND=""`:
TERM is the environment variable to tell which Shell features you are capable of, while PS1, PS2 and PROMPT_COMMAND are variables which control what should show up as a prompt

```
if test -r /etc/os-release; then source /etc/os-release && test xLinux Mint = x$ID && exit; fi
if test -x /usr/bin/lsb_release; then /usr/bin/lsb_release -i 2>/dev/null | grep -qi Linux Mint && exit; fi
if test -r /etc/issue; then cat /etc/issue | grep -qi Linux Mint && exit; fi
[ -x /usr/bin/lsb_release ] && /usr/bin/lsb_release -i 2>/dev/null | grep Trisquel
```

And this seems to be some code that determines which system is running.
`lsb_release` prints which LSB modules are available.
`/etc/os-release` contains information about the Distro used.